# Program outputs wrong output

Tags: python, debugging

I'm doing this for a school project and need to know why the output keeps spitting out "Estonia", even when the conditions don't meet. Also, why does the program put a "None" in some places?
 I'm not sure if I should include all my code or just a part though, so I'll put the whole thing just in case. I'm new, so please bare with my idocracy...

```
# Purpose: Create a program that suggests a vacation spot based on user input


# Here is the Input, or answers to the questions
print('Hello! This is your Dream Vacation Spot!')
answers = [input('Do you want a "hot" or "cold" place? '),
        input('Do you want a place that has a "huge" pop or "small" pop? '),
        input('Are you planning on getting wet? "y" or "n": ')]

# Create the intro that displays what they said. 
def intro():
    for i in range(2):
        print('')
    print('Hi! Welcome to your Dream Vacation Spot!')
    print('')
    print('Listed here, are your answers:')
    print('Hot or cold place? You said ' + answers[0])
    print('Huge population, or small towny place? You said ' + answers[1])
    print('Want to get wet? You said ' + answers[2])
    for i in range(2):
        print('')

# Start using the if/ elif statements to decide places to go.
def main():
    if answers[0] == 'cold' and answers[1] == 'small' and answers[2] == 'wet' or 'Wet':
        one = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Estonia!'
        print(one)

    elif answers[0] == 'cold' or 'Cold' and answers[1] == 'big' or 'Big' and answers[2] == 'y' or 'Y':
        two = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Geirangerfjord, Norway!'
        print(two)

    elif answers[0] == 'cold' or 'Cold' and answers[1] == 'small' or 'Small' and answers[2] == 'n' or 'N':
        three = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Innsbruck, Austria!'
        print(three)

    elif answers[0] == 'cold' or 'Cold' and answers[1] == 'big' or 'Big' and answers[2] == 'n' or 'N':
        four = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Yellowknife, Canada!'
        print(four)

    elif answers[0] == 'hot' or 'Hot' and answers[1] == 'big' or 'Big' and answers[2] == 'n' or 'N':
        five = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Austin, Texas!'
        print(five)

    elif answers[0] == 'hot' or 'Hot' and answers[1] == 'small' or 'Small' and answers[2] == 'n' or 'N':
        six = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Bisbee, Arizona!'
        print(six)

    elif answers[0] == 'hot' or 'Hot' and answers[1] == 'small' or 'Small' and answers[2] == 'n' or 'N':
        seven = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Grand Junction, Colorado!'
        print(seven)

    elif answers[0] == 'hot' or 'Hot' and answers[1] == 'small' or 'Small' and answers[2] == 'y' or 'Y':
        eight = 'Congrats!! You got... \n Muskogee, Oklahoma!'
        print(eight)



def printAll():
    print(intro())
    print(main())
    for i in range(2):
        print('')
    print('Have a nice trip!!!')

printAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Phew! that is a lot of code and there are probably some great lessons on how to deal with convoluted logic, lets see if we can't just make it work a bit better.

First I'd suggest you use list comprehension and the lower() function to simplify the number of possibilities in answers

```
answers_lowercase = [x.lower() for x in answers]
```

then why not use a single logical test in your if/elif statements, something like

```
def main():
    if answers_lowercase == ['cold', 'small', 'wet'] :
        print('Congrats!! You got... \n Estonia!')
```

There are probably even more concise, pythonic ways of writing out your code: i.e. looking up the correct answer from a table instead of using six "if" statements, and error handling if the user puts something wrong in the inputs. Good things to look into and learn from. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can change your conditions to use "in" keyword to avoid confusion between "and", "or"
eg. *answers[0] in ('cold','Cold') and answers[1] in ('big','Big') and answers[2] in ('y','Y')*

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies in the if statements. When you check for `or` condition surround it with a bracket.

eg. `answers[0] == ('cold' or 'Cold') and answers[1] == ('big' or 'Big') and answers[2] == ('y' or 'Y')`

Comment: This is still wrong, just in a slightly different way.